# How to use path with parameters in breadcrumbs on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, breadcrumbs

I just want to use a path with parameters with breadcrumbs on rails gem:

```
gem "breadcrumbs_on_rails"
```

It perfectly works without parameters in path :

```
add_breadcrumb "Edit series", shelf_label_series_path
```

But with parameters, the html render works without errors but the link is not active (as you can see in the screenshot):

```
add_breadcrumb @series['name_fr'], edit_series_path(:series_id => params[:series_id], :shop_id => params[:shop_id], :shelf_id => params[:shelf_id])
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Do you have any ideas of the reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: You can do `edit_series_path(params.slice(:series_id, :shop_id, :shelf_id))` instead of literally copying the values to new hash.

Comment: Does `edit_series_path(params.slice(:series_id, :shop_id, :shelf_id))` return the same path as the `request.fullpath`? Otherwise that would explain why its not active.

Comment: no it doesn't, it returns: /shelf_label/edit_series?series_id=5199&shelf_id=10&shop_id=2 when I use params.slice(:series_id, :shop_id, :shelf_id). But the link is active... wtf?

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: why it explain that it's not active?

Comment: Because BreadcrumbOnRails uses [link_to_unless_current](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless_current) when [creating the links](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails/blob/d389feac27b507e857462127118da46447be8136/lib/breadcrumbs_on_rails/breadcrumbs.rb#L91).

Answer (score 0):

`add_breadcrumb` accepts a Proc. In your example, you can just do this in your controller action:

```
add_breadcrumb "Edit series", Proc.new{ shelf_label_series_path((:series_id => params[:series_id], :shop_id => params[:shop_id], :shelf_id => params[:shelf_id])) }
```